# I cannot import fonts using font_import

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts

I am trying to import fonts for ggplot2 graphs as in described [here](https://rachelcoy.co.uk/blog/2018/02/28/change-ggplot-font-type-extrafont/).

When I try do to so piece by piece with this code :

```
font_import(pattern = "Arial.ttf")
y
```

I get this error :

```
canning ttf files in C:\windows\Fonts ...
Extracting .afm files from .ttf files...
Error in data.frame(fontfile = ttfiles, FontName = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1
```

I have checked that I have indeed the Arial font : 
[image]

What is my problem

Comment: The `pattern` is case sensitive, it seems. Try `font_import(pattern = "arial.ttf")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Really check the file name

**tl;dr** Windows is case-insensitive, but R's `grepl` is not, and `import_font` passes the pattern argument `grepl`

Use:

```
extrafont::font_import(pattern="arial.ttf", prompt=FALSE)
```

Why? Because Windows returns "arial.ttf" as the file name.

### File Explorer doesn't show font file names

The pattern "Arial.ttf" would match `C:\Windows\Fonts\Arial.ttf`.  However on my test system the file is just `C:\Windows\Fonts\Arial` without an extension.  This is what you see when looking at the directory using File Explorer.  File Explorer is not showing you the file names as illustrated below.

### Look for font file with R or powershell

The output of the file name via any of these methods is `arial.ttf`.

#### Using powershell

```
ls C:\Windows\Fonts | findstr -i arial
gci -Path "C:\Windows\Fonts" -Recurse -File -Filter "arial.ttf"
gci -Path "C:\Windows\Fonts" -Recurse -File -Filter "Arial.ttf"
```

all show the filename `arial.ttf`.

#### Using R

```
# font_import lists files using this function
list.files("C:/Windows/Fonts", pattern="\\.ttf") # shows arial.ttf

file.exists("C:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf") # TRUE
file.exists("C:/Windows/Fonts/Arial.ttf") # TRUE b/c Windows is case-insensitive
```

### How `font_import` uses pattern argument

Looking into how `font_import` uses the pattern supplied:

```
extrafont::font_import # prints the source
#function (paths = NULL, recursive = TRUE, prompt = TRUE, pattern = NULL) 
#{
#...
#    ttf_import(paths, recursive, pattern)
#}

extrafont:::ttf_import # print the source
#function (paths = NULL, recursive = TRUE, pattern = NULL) 
#{
#    if (is.null(paths)) 
#        paths <- ttf_find_default_path()
#    ttfiles <- normalizePath(list.files(paths, pattern = "\\.ttf$", 
#        full.names = TRUE, recursive = recursive, ignore.case = TRUE))
#    if (!is.null(pattern)) {
#        matchfiles <- grepl(pattern, basename(ttfiles))
#        ttfiles <- ttfiles[matchfiles]
#    }
#...
#}
```

The line where the supplied pattern gets used is in a call to `grepl`

```
matchfiles <- grepl(pattern, basename(ttfiles))
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. However, I get the error I mention when I try `extrafont::font_import(pattern="Arial$", prompt=FALSE) `, that is to say I still have : `Scanning ttf files in C:\windows\Fonts ...
Extracting .afm files from .ttf files...
Error in data.frame(fontfile = ttfiles, FontName = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1`

Comment: Can you verify that the Arial font file exists?

Comment: It does exist (I add a picture in my initial question).

Comment: @AnthonyMartin The error is the result of passing an empty character vector to `ttf_extract( )`.  That's the result of not finding the font file.  So the question is now, why isn't there a font file matching the pattern "Arial" found?

Comment: @AnthonyMartin in powershell took a look in the Fonts directory for arial.  `ls C:\Windows\Fonts | findstr -i 'arial'` and it shows up as `arial.ttf`.  Looks like capitalization is the issue.  Try `pattern="arial.ttf".  Seems that Windows File Explorer is _helpfully_ displaying ttf font files with a different name than thier filename.

Comment: Thank you for all the effort. I do get your points and it indeed changes the result, but it unfortunately brings me back to square one, as `extrafont::font_import(pattern="arial.ttf", prompt=FALSE) ` gets me the first error message, with the `'CreateProcess' failed to run`...

Comment: @AnthonyMartin at least your R issue is solved.  This gets you back to you OS level problem of not being able to spawn a child process running the exe specified in the error message. Which is probably a separate SO question.

Comment: I think my initial question covered both subjects but I will edit it so that tis one is about the second part so that someone might find that the font displayed is not necessarily the one to grab, and create a new one as you suggested.

Answer (score 7):

I was having the same problem, i.e. trying to import a font (Zallman Caps) using `font_import()` and receiving the same error:

```
"Error in data.frame(fontfile = ttfiles, FontName = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : 
   arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1"
```

After a lot of trial and error, I finally found a solution that worked for me and perhaps it will for you, as well.

Even though I could see the Zallman Caps font in my Windows Fonts folder and verified that it worked in Word, neither `font_import()` nor `list.files()` could find it there. I managed to import the font by entering the following code:

```
font_import(path = "C:/Users/*insert your user name*/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Fonts", pattern = ".TTF")
```

I have no idea why it isn't visible to R in the main fonts directory, when I can clearly see it in Windows file explorer, but at least I managed to import the font using this workaround.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Argh, thank you! This is the answer that I've been looking for all these years!